# Why is react is not rerendering after setstate

Tags: reactjs, setstate

In below code for react I am trying to change button colours by updating a dictionary. Unfortunately it is not working unless I force the rerender.

```js
const jsonFromDatabase = [{ "id": 1, "name": "Ka" },
{ "id": 2, "name": "Erd" }];

const json = [{ "id": 2, "name": "Ka" },
{ "id": 3, "name": "Erd" }];
class ControllableButton extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      color_black: true,
      datasetForDisplay: json,
      datasetForStorage: jsonFromDatabase
    }
  }

  onClickGroupToUpdate = (cell, row, rowIndex) => {
    let toAdd = { "id": row.id, "name": row.name }
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      datasetForStorage: prevState.datasetForStorage.push(toAdd)
    })
    console.log("updated the database")
    console.log(this.state.datasetForStorage)
    // this.forceUpdate()
  }

  onClickGroupSelected = (cell, row, rowIndex) => {
  }

  // cellButton should be modified each time of click
  cellButton = (cell, row, enumObject, rowIndex) => {
    let theButton
    let inDB = false
    console.log(row)
    for (var group in this.state.datasetForStorage) {
      if (this.state.datasetForStorage[group].id == row.id) {
        inDB = true
      }
    }
    if (inDB) {
      theButton = <button style={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }}
        type="button"
        onClick={() => this.onClickGroupSelected(cell, row, rowIndex)}>
        In database
               </button>
      console.log('already in database' + row.id)
    } else {
      theButton = <button style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}
        type="button"
        onClick={() => this.onClickGroupToUpdate(cell, row, rowIndex)}>
        Update database
               </button>
      console.log('not in  database' + row.id)
    }
    return theButton
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BootstrapTable data={this.state.datasetForDisplay} >
        <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='id' width='100'>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name' width='300'>Group Name</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='button' width='100' dataFormat={this.cellButton}>Generate Group Page</TableHeaderColumn>
      </BootstrapTable>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ControllableButton />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Above code is not re-rendering after each click on updating the group, unless I forceUpdate. Can you help me to figure out what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) correctly and on top of that you are mutating it, [which you shouldn't](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state).

Instead of this:

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
  datasetForStorage: prevState.datasetForStorage.push(toAdd)
})
```

You can just pass a plain object:

```
this.setState({
  datasetForStorage: [...this.state.datasetForStorage,toAdd]
})
```

or pass the function like you did but note the `()` around the object so we actually return an object:

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
  datasetForStorage: [...prevState.datasetForStorage,toAdd]
}))
```

Arrow functions are returning implicitly but won't return if you use the curly brackets

```
() => {}
```

so you have to wrap them with parentheses

```
() => ({})
```

I have used the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) which help us create a new array easily.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `setState()` with an updater function, that function needs to return an object that represents the data to be merged. You aren't returning anything, so your updater function actually returns `undefined`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals

Another issue is that you should copy the array in your state, push new data into that, and then use it to update. Never mutate what is held in your state directly.

```
onClickGroupToUpdate = (cell, row, rowIndex) => {
    let toAdd = { "id": row.id, "name": row.name }
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      // Copy the array that you have in state
      let datasetForStorageCopy = prevState.datasetForStorage.slice();
      datasetForStorageCopy.push(toAdd)
      // Return a new object describing the state change
      return {datasetForStorage: datasetForStorageCopy}
    })
    console.log("updated the database")
    console.log(this.state.datasetForStorage)
    // this.forceUpdate()
}
```